# Batching of data in Distributed Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am very new to Tensorflow and so my question may sound really stupid, but I couldn't really find a proper explanation so asking it here. 
I need your help to understand how batching or distribution of data takes place in a within graph distributed Tensorflow program.

Since we execute multiple clients, which essentially has same code to get the next batch:

```
batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
```

I fail to understand how would this ensure unique batch to very worker. To me it seems as if same data is being sent to all the workers.

Here in this example script on every iteration we are reading next_batch and since we are running two clients with job_type=worker, both the workers will see same next_batch code. Please help me understand in this scenario how would data parallelism work.

```
 with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target, config=sess_config) as sess:
        print("Worker %d: Session initialization complete." % FLAGS.task_index)
        # Loop until the supervisor shuts down or 1000000 steps have completed.
        step = 0
        while not sv.should_stop() and step < 1000000:
            # Run a training step asynchronously.
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
            print("FETCHING NEXT BATCH %d" % FLAGS.batch_size)
            train_feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}

            _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
            if step % 100 == 0:
                print("Done step %d" % step)

    # Ask for all the services to stop.
    sv.stop()
```

Looking forward to your help in this.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code of `mnist.train.next_batch` and`next_batch` ([in tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py)) which is the function that is called by mnist.train.next_batch:
-  every worker will have a separate `DataSet` object that will be used to generate the data. So each batch will be generated independently for each worker.

- every datapoint may be used more than once per epoch across workers, but the subsets are taken at random so that is potentially not a problem. Even though some workers may see the same data points, the batches themselves are generated randomly

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Yes, I see your point but i don't see it as data parallelism, end of it I don't really see a gain by distributing my work load. Instead if I could give different batches to them (which is guaranteed to be not duplicate across workers) I could save some time and hence some benefit. Do you agree or am I missing some thing here?